# PHP, using sleep my screen frozen until sleep is complete

Tags: php, function, sleep

i'm trying to create a randomgenerator that each 5 seconds echo a new number by using rand. Only problem is when i add the sleep to it it feels like its frozen my page while not bee showing my screen freezes and i have to close the application else the application just crash.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    class Numbergenerator
    {
        public function randomNumber(){
            $gameIsOn = true;
            while(true){
                echo rand(1, 75);
                sleep(5);
            }
        }
    }
    $test = new numbergenerator();

    $test->randomNumber();
```

Why is my screen freezing ?, what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, so the page will not finish loading until the script has completed.

Comment: why cant you use ajax with jquery. so that will load only required div or element for every 5 min.

Comment: Is there any way how i can force this ?

Comment: There is way how to force server to flush data.

Comment: Okay, thx than i will use jQuery or Ajax thx guys!